# Compress unordered collection of hashes

Tags: algorithm, compression

My collection of 10M 16-byte hashes (MD5) occupies, unsurprisingly, 160 MB on disk.

- How could I compress this, if reordering is allowed?
- What is the theoretical maximum compression rate for this kind of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cryptographic hashes basically look like random numbers as far as compression goes, so a scheme like Elias–Fano will be about the best possible. The high-level idea is to sort the hashes, choose u + ℓ = 128 depending on the number of hashes, encode the sequence of differences of the upper u bits in unary, and the lower ℓ bits in binary. For details, there are a lot of articles about Elias–Fano, e.g., [this one](https://medium.com/@wolfgarbe/elias-fano-quasi-succinct-compression-of-sorted-integers-in-c-89f92a8c9986), so I won't attempt to write another here.

Comment: Very cool, I hadn't heard of this encoding approach before.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the amount of data stored at the cost of increasing the number of files.  Essentially do something like a partial radix sort, storing all the hashes with the same starting bits in the same file, but not actually storing the starting bits themselves, as they are implicit from the file they are in.  There would need to be some processing to remove the starting bits before storing and to restore those bits on retrieval.

With 256 separate files: file00 to fileFF say, you could save one byte per hash, a total of 10MB storage saved.  With a hash value 0x3F78A2... you would store the truncated 15 bytes of data: 0x78A2... in file3F and restore the leading byte when retrieving.  For searching you could look for a truncated target in the correct file, which should be faster then searching the entire database.

With 16 files you would only save 4 bits per hash and other variations are possible.

You will have to judge if some such scheme is suitable for your requirements.  As with so many things, saving space requires extra processing.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience your can compress around 30%-60%. Use gzip or zip. Since hash output is random, no other tricks would work.

Note: since the hash output does not use all possible ascii bits this rate might be much higher

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. Both gzip and xz produce _larger_ files. But I suspect there is opportunity for optimization, if you can re-order the hashes.

Comment: Also my MD5 hashes are 16 byte, not 32 byte hex representations.

Answer (score 0):

A series of MD5 hashes appear, for all intensive purposes, to be random data. It cannot be compressed losslessly.

The amount of information contained in the unsorted order of 10<sup>7</sup> hashes comes out to about 22 bits per hash. So even if you sorted them (not sure why that would be ok), the theoretically best compression could get is a 17% reduction. Hardly worth the effort.

The only thing I could suggest would be consider what false positive rate you could accept, and simply throw away some of the MD5 hash bits. You may not need all 128.

Comment: Thanks. How do you arrive at 22 significant bits per hash?

Comment: log2(10^7!)/10^7